# Accessing continuous voice recognition in Android 4.0

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am trying to get continuous voice input to work in my Android application. I tried using the built-in `SpeechRecognizer` Intent but it waits for the user to finish speaking before processing the words. This is not sufficient for me. I need the device to process the words while the user is still speaking.

I read that this is supported in Ice Cream Sandwich now. However, I did not find any API that allows me to access this feature. Does anyone know how this works now?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you heard about the new voice typing feature of Android 4.0. Take a look at this [article](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/12/add-voice-typing-to-your-ime.html).

You have to use an external library for it. Though the article says the library is designed for IME developers, and as I see the result of voice recognition will appear in a registered IME through InputMethodService. You can also check the source of the library, because it is a [project on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/google-voice-typing-integration)

Comment: Finally I found time for trying this out. thanks for your response! I found that article too, but initially I thought it might also work in an application itself, without using an IME.
So now I have to wait for an ICS ROM for my phone to try out the voice typing. Unfortunately, I didn't succeed in getting audio input to work in the emulator.